# Find unique values in R but annotate them based on another column

Tags: r, dataframe, unique

So I have a dataframe like so:

```
summary(deg)
      L2FC            Gene                    diffexp    comp   
 Min.   :-3.825   Length:926         Downregulated:210   A:195  
 1st Qu.: 1.010   Class :character   Upregulated  :716   B:731  
 Median : 1.163   Mode  :character                              
 Mean   : 0.860                                                 
 3rd Qu.: 1.431                                                 
 Max.   : 6.505    

head(deg)
       L2FC    Gene       diffexp comp
1 -2.754236 SLC13A2 Downregulated    A
2  3.161623   SNAI2   Upregulated    A
3 -2.821350   STYK1 Downregulated    A
4 -1.798022    CD84 Downregulated    A
5 -1.293536    TLE6 Downregulated    A
6 -1.011016   P2RX1 Downregulated    A
```

What I want is simply the unique gene symbols annotated based on whether they are in A only, B only, or shared across both.  Desired output is like this:

```
   Gene comp
1 GENE1    1
2 GENE2    0
3 GENE3   -1
```

Where the Gene column only has the unique values from deg and the comp shows +1 for belonging to only A, -1 for belonging to only B, or 0 for belonging to both.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(tidyverse)

deg |>
  summarize(
    comp = any(comp == "A") - any(comp == "B"),
    .by = Gene
  )
```

Comment: With this I get:

Error in quickdf(.data[names(cols)]) : length(rows) == 1 is not TRUE

Comment: I switched to dplyr::summarize, seems to be working great, thank you!

Comment: Without some sample data, I can't test the code.  Two ideas.  (1) Make sure you have the latest version of `tidyverse`.  (2)  If you have the latest version of tidyverse and you still have problems, see what happens if you use `reframe` instead of `summarize`.

Comment: why do you use `sum`?? just use `any(comp == 'A') - any(comp == 'B')`